# Store and access Screen Time history?

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

I find Screen Time very useful for keeping track of my device usage and habits, and I’d like to be able to look back at its history over time, like how I can review my step count and other Health data.  The iPhone’s normal Screen Time viewer (under Settings) shows the last 4 weeks of data, but no further

**Is there a way to store a longer history of Screen Time data (if it’s not already stored by default) and review/browse/analyse this data, either with Apple software or third-party apps?**

I’m primarily interested in iPhone Screen Time data, but also in solutions for other iOS/MacOS devices.  I’d prefer to have a nice interface for browsing the history, like the standard Screen Time viewer, but if that’s not available, I’d also be happy to access the underlying data in any format.

Comment: The only one I know of is using TimingApp (https://timingapp.com/?lang=en), but its paid. I'm also looking for a solution